# Matplotlib lables aren’t displaying

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi i am trying to plot a graph with some information, the graph is plotted completely fine but I can’t get the labels to appear on the x and y axis. Would anyone know where I’ve went wrong?

```
with open(“student.txt”, “r”) as S:
 contents = S.read()
 amountWales = contents.count(‘Wales’)
 amountScotland= contents.count(‘Scotland’)
 amountEngland = contents.count(‘England’)

figure = plt.figure()
axis = figure.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
countries = [‘England’ ,’Scotland’, ‘Wales]
amountCountries = [amountEngland, amountScotland, anountWales]
axis.bar(countries, amountCountries)
plt.ylabel(‘Value’)
plt.xlabel(‘Country’)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The sample data is: B123, Jones, Scotland      B134,Smith, Wales

Comment: edit your question and add sample data/file

Comment: Do i need to add sample data, the data side of it works. It’s just the labels that won’t appear

Comment: The problem is `axis = figure.add_axes([0,0,1,1])` which occupies the full figure without leaving space for ticks, labels and titles.  The recommended way would be to use default positioning.  E.g. `figure, axis = plt.subplots()`.  See the matplotlib tutorials, e.g. [introduction - basic usage](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py)